# Crop Image on client side and upload cropped image

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, upload, crop

I'm looking for crop and upload plugin in AngularJs, scenario is:

1. Browse an Image
2. Crop the image
3. Upload the cropped image not the original image

Is there any optimized way to implement this on client side?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your tags I can see you're using `angularjs` for your client side app. The are many cropping modules out there, but I am personally using this [ng-img-cropper](https://github.com/AllanBishop/angular-img-cropper) by Allan Bishop for cropping and [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) for uploading. Easy to use and straight forward.